# simulate autoregressive data that is also multivariate normal

Tags: r, normal-distribution, simulation, autoregressive

I am trying to simulate data that is correlated to varying degrees. However, the data itself will have a degree of autocorrelation as well. I can get the first part of the problem with mvrnorm function using this code:

```
library(MASS)    

set.seed(1531488844)

# Generate random data values



r <- 0.95
xrow = 10 
ySigma <- matrix(
  c(1  , r  , r^2, r^3, r^4, r^5, r^6, r^7, r^8, r^9,
    r  , 1  , r  , r^2, r^3, r^4, r^5, r^6, r^7, r^8,
    r^2, r  , 1  , r  , r^2, r^3, r^4, r^5, r^6, r^7,
    r^3, r^2, r  , 1  , r  , r^2, r^3, r^4, r^5, r^6,
    r^4, r^3, r^2, r  , 1  , r  , r^2, r^3, r^4, r^5,
    r^5, r^4, r^3, r^2, r  , 1  , r  , r^2, r^3, r^4,
    r^6, r^5, r^4, r^3, r^2, r  , 1  , r  , r^2, r^3,
    r^7, r^6, r^5, r^4, r^3, r^2, r  , 1  , r  , r^2,
    r^8, r^7, r^6, r^5, r^4, r^3, r^2, r  , 1  , r  ,
    r^9, r^8, r^7, r^6, r^5, r^4, r^3, r^2, r  , 1  ),
  nrow = xrow
)

rawvars <- mvrnorm(n=10000, mu=rep(0,xrow), Sigma=ySigma)

pairs(rawvars[1:100,])
```

[image: mvrnorm output]

BUT the problem is that each individual column is white noise and looks like this:

[image: its white noise]

What I would like to have is each column of data follow an autoregressive process so it looks like this:

[image: arima.sim]

I know that mvrnorm can't create autoregressive data - but I was thinking there may be a way to accomplish what I am after by combining the two functions.